# Pop up login in navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a pop up login in navigation. I want it to not go back in the previous page whenever I click one of the textboxes and when I only click the exit or "x" button it will exit. I don't know what's the problem with my code. Can someone help me?

```html
<body> 
  <div class=MainNavi>
   <div class=SecNavi>  
    <ul>
       <div class="login">
                       <li> <a href="#form" Onclick="onClick(this)" id = "log101">Login</a> 
                       <div id="m01" class="modal-popup" onclick="this.style.display='#form'">
                              <img class="modal-popup-content " id="img01" style="width:80%">
                              <div class="login-container">
                                  <img src="images/user-login.png">
                                  <div id = "form">
  
                                     <form action="" method="post" id="myform">
                                     <div class = "form-input">
                                           <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "form-input">
                                           <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter  Password" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                       <input type="submit" class=btn-login name="log" value="Let me in">
                                 </div>
                            </form>
 
                       </div>
                       <span id ="x101"Onclick="onClick(this).this.style.display='none'"" class="x-   btn x-hover display-x">x</span>
            <script>
               function onClick(element) {
                  document.getElementById("log101").src = element.src;
                  document.getElementById("m01").style.display = "block";
               }
          </script>
 </div>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Songs</a></li>
     <li><a href="Gallery.htm">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="Home.htm">Home</a></li>
      <center><h1>#</h1></center>
 </ul>
     
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your html is too wrong ul can only contain li elements not div .

Comment: so how can make an onclick navi?

Comment: first write correct html then you can go for js .